# Sybase ASE 15.7: Create Trigger such that before inserting I want to modify row being inserted

Tags: database, sybase, sybase-ase15

I am using Sybase ASE 15.7. I wish to create trigger before insert such that before inserting, I want to modify some fields in the inserted row.

Please help Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From a trigger perspective you have a couple options:

- `for insert` trigger; must be defined against the base table; this trigger will fire **after** the data has been inserted to the table; the trigger would be coded to perform updates against the base table of the newly inserted row
- `instead of` trigger; must be defined against a view (the view would be defined against the base table); you would perform your insert against the view which would cause the `instead of` trigger to fire; the trigger would be coded to copy/manipulate the data from the `inserted` pseudo-table and write the final data set into the base table

See [create trigger](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1572/html/commands/X19955.htm) for more details.

---

Another option would be to write a stored procedure that does all of the pre-insert changes; instead of inserting directly to the base table you would call the stored proc (passing in all of the column values as input parameters). [granted, less than ideal]

'course one other option would be to have the application perform the pre-insert checks and edits before inserting the final data set to the base table.

Comment: So there is no way we can do before insert  directly in trigger itself like we do in Oracle?

Comment: I cannot do in application. Insert comes from varied places

Comment: if you cannot modify the `varied places` to perform inserts against a view (with a `instead of` trigger on the view) then, no, you won't be able to pre-modify the data before it's inserted into the table